# How do I install the new GNS3 release?

Tags: software-installation

The GNS3 package in Ubuntu Software Center is old. I tried to install the new release GNS3 0.8.4 RC2 from the CLI using the following command:

`sudo python gns3 0.8.4 exe` (and bin) but I get a python error.

I have updated python and still get the same error.

The GNS installation instructions ar for using the Ubuntu Software Xenter for the installation but the newer releases are not found when I search for them. The releases are on my disk drive.

How can I install the packages?

Comment: Could you add the output errors to your question? As well as a link to the install instructions? This will help us understand your problem better.l

Answer (score 1):

You can easily install gns3 with these commands:

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg
sudo pip3 install gns3-gui
sudo pip3 install gns3-server
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to start [GNS3](http://www.gns3.com/) from the command line, use the following command:

`sudo python gns3`

There is no need for the additional options on the command line.

**Instructions for installing GNS3 from source**

GNS3 is a graphical network simulator. In order to emulate Cisco network devices, the `dynamips` emulator will need to be installed as well.

1. Install the following recommended packages:

   `sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools`

   `sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools`
2. Before downloading the files for GNS, create the following two
   directories:

   `sudo mkdir /opt/GNS3`

   `sudo mkdir /opt/GNS3/Dynamips`
3. Go to the [GNS download page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gns-3/files/GNS3/)
   for the latest version (The latest version is 0.8.4-RC2) or download directly from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gns-3/files/GNS3/0.8.4-RC2/GNS3-0.8.4-RC2-src.tar.bz2/download).
4. Go to the [dynamips download page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gns-3/files/Dynamips/):

   - Select the latest version (currently 0.2.8-RC3-community) depending upon your machine architecture.
   - [64-bit version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gns-3/files/Dynamips/0.2.8-RC3-community/dynamips-0.2.8-RC3-community-x86_64.bin/download)
   - [32-bit version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gns-3/files/Dynamips/0.2.8-RC3-community/dynamips-0.2.8-RC3-community-x86.bin/download)
5. Go to the folder where you downloaded the two files.

   - Unpack the GNS files:
   - `sudo tar -jxf GNS3-0.8.4-RC2-src.tar.bz2`
   - Move the files to the `/opt/GNS3` directory:

     - `sudo mv GNS3-0.8.2-src/* /opt/GNS3`
   - Move the dynamips binary to the `/opt/GNS3/Dynamips` directory:

     - `sudo mv dynamips-0.2.8-RC2-x86.bin /opt/GNS3/Dynamips`
   - Change the permissions on the Dynamips binary to make it executable:

     - `sudo chmod +x /opt/GNS3/Dynamips/dynamips-0.2.8-RC2-x86.bin`
6. Start GNS3

   - `sudo python gns3`

I would recommend taking a look at the following video from the GNS3 team for further instructions and decent explanation of validating the rest of your GNS3 installation.

[GNS3 installation tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CuMn9x96x8).
There is also updated [GNS3 installation instructions for Linux](https://www.gns3.com/support/docs/linux-installation) on the main GNS3 site.

Answer (score 0):

online method to install Gns3 easy way ?

1. `sudo su`
   2 enter your root password
2. `apt-get update`
3. `apt-get upgrade` < optional>
4. `apt-get install gns3`

... that's all

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gns3`  will install gns...

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu-based distributions (64-bit only)**

Run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gns3-gui
```

If you want IOU support:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gns3-iou
```

Check these documents

1. https://gns3.com/support/docs/linux-installation
2. https://gns3.com/support/docs/installing-gns3-1-4-on-ubuntu-li